# Prove that: $\frac{1}{ka+b}+\frac{1}{kb+c}+\frac{1}{kc+a}\ge\frac{6}{(k+1)\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$

Tags: inequality

**Problem:** Let $a,b,c>0; k\ge1$. Prove that: $$\frac{1}{ka+b}+\frac{1}{kb+c}+\frac{1}{kc+a}\ge\frac{6}{(k+1)\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$$
**My attempt:** Using C-S inequality: $$\frac{1}{ka+b}+\frac{1}{kb+c}+\frac{1}{kc+a}\ge\frac{9}{(k+1)(a+b+c)}$$

It is desired to prove: $$\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)$$ Which is false.
The problem has nice form but for me, it is quite hard to get nice proof. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: BW still helps. It's proof, but it's very ugly.

Comment: Actually, it is my teacher problem. He said AM-GM works, so i think it is old problem. Have you seen it before, sir?

Comment: This is very nice, but hard to get nice proof

Comment: It's obvious for $k\geq2+\sqrt5$.

Comment: And for else part?. I just prove it by k=1

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg How did you get a proof for k≥2+\sqrt{5}

Comment: I proved it for any $1\leq k\leq1.2674...$ and $k\geq1.7237...$

Comment: If you have time, please share with us.

Comment: The problem is really nightmare to me. Unthinkable AM-GM to me, anyone help me?

Answer (score -1):

I just get a part by AM-GM. Maybe stronger tools can help to make up the rest $1<k<2$

For $k=1$: the inequality holds obviously by AM-GM

For $k\ge2$: Using C-S inequality: $$k(a+b+c)\sum{\frac{1}{ka+b}}=3+(k-1)\sum{\frac{b}{ka+b}}+k\sum{\frac{c}{ka+b}}\ge\frac{6k}{k+1}+\frac{k(a+b+c)^2}{(k+1)(ab+bc+ca)}$$Also by AM-GM inequality and well- known result:  $9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge8(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)$, we obtain:
$$2.\frac{3k}{k+1}+\frac{k(a+b+c)^2}{(k+1)(ab+bc+ca)}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{9k^3}{(k+1)^3}.\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca}}\ge\frac{6k(a+b+c)}{(k+1)\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$$Hence, the proof is cleared!

Comment: Can you clarify how you used CS for $k \ge 2$ please?

Comment: I think CS help for k is greater than 2

Comment: My question was can you explain how C-S was used? I do not understand the C-S application. Can you provide some details?

Comment: $$(k-1)\sum{\frac{b}{ka+b}}\ge\frac{3(k-1)}{k+1}$$